# Pass reactive or static value to the same shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

I've got the same module called 2 time within my application. In one of the call I've a "static" data.frame while in the second call I would like to pass a reactive value.

Is it possible to pass reactive and static value to the same shiny module?
If this is not possible should be better to develop 2 version of the same module or convert to reactive also the other data frame?

```
#--- Reactive Values  ----
reactive_selected_account  <- reactive({ input$budget_slider })
reactive_monthly_total     <- reactive({
    monthly_total %>%
        filter( account==reactive_selected_account() ) %>%
        group_by(dt) %>%
        select(-account) %>%
        function_do_monthly_total()
})

#--- Components Calls ----
callModule(component_srv, "istance1", data=monthly_total)
callModule(component_srv, "istance1", data=reactive_monthly_total() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the module in a way where a reactive value is expected

```r
component_srv <- function(input, output, session, reactive_parameter) {
  observeEvent(reactive_parameter(), {
    # ...
  }
  # ...
}
```

Then you can choose to pass a static value by just wrapping `reactive()` around it.

```r
static_object <- iris
callModule(component_srv, "instance", 
           reactive_parameter = reactive(static_object))
```

```r
reactive_object = reactive({
  get_data(input$dataset)
})
callModule(component_srv, "instance2",
           reactive_parameter = reactive_object)
```

Note that you need to use `reactive_object` rather than `reactive_object()` in `callModule()` to make this work.

Comment: Nice, so basically your proposal is to convert to reactive values all the module instances. I think this is reasonable and it’s more or less the solution I’ve also fulgerei out :) ... Are there any downside, in terms of performance, I’ve to worry about?

Comment: I don't know about the performance implications when you use reactive() around static objects. There is certainly some overhead but I suggest you do some benchmarking to figure out if it the difference is significant. Also note that reactive() creates a cache so monitoring RAM usage might be a good idea as well.